# How do I configure a POST route in Play Framework v1.2.7 with a dynamic id attribute that will load a JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, routes, playframework-1.x

I would like to have an http route "POST /users/2" that submits a form to a controller with action signature Application.saveUser(User user) that will update the details for an existing user based on the entity id specified a dynamic argument in the URL. The type User is a JPA entity and the Play support for JPA will automatically load the entity if a parameter "user.id" is specified in the request/form. Up until now I've been specifying the "user.id" as a hidden input but I really want the id to be part of the URL.

My first idea to include the user id in the URL was to define a route like this:

```
POST /users/{user.id}   Application.saveUser()
```

Unfortunately this gives the following exception:

```
Oops: PatternSyntaxException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception PatternSyntaxException: unknow class: {user.id}

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:244)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:286)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: jregex.PatternSyntaxException: unknow class: {member.id}
    at jregex.CharacterClass.parseName(jregex/CharacterClass.java:361)
    at jregex.Term.append(jregex/Term.java:482)
    at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:259)
    at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:219)
    at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:206)
    at jregex.Pattern.compile(jregex/Pattern.java:164)
    at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:150)
    at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:108)
    at play.mvc.Router$Route.compute(Router.java:755)
```

Another option I tried was to just use an 'id' argument name hoping Play might be able to match that to the user id attribute:

```
POST /users/{id}   Application.saveUser()
```

But this gives the expected NoRouteFoundException because 'id' does not match the action method argument name 'user'. The final obvious option is to use the argument name 'user' and again hoping Play might use some intelligence to work out this is the id:

```
POST /users/{user}   Application.saveUser()
```

This does enable the page to render with the correct route specified in the form but upon submit the correct JPA entity is not loaded:

```
<form action="/users/3" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

The final way I did try was to do a mapping but not sure if this is supported:

```
POST /users/{user}   Application.saveUser(user.id: user)
```

Again the correct JPA entity is not loaded. I've searched high and low but found no example of how this can be done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the play documentation which shows an approach to your question:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/jpa#save 
(the seconde code snippet in this chapter)

You need a route (like you suggested in your second approach), where you just pass the id of the model you want to edit:

```
POST /users/{id}   Application.saveUser()
```

The according action method could look like this:

```
public static void save(Long id) {
    User user = User.findById(id);  // here you load the entity you want to edit by it's id
    user.edit("user", params.all());  // here the entity will be edited
    validation.valid(user);
    if(validation.hasErrors()) {
        edit(id);
    } else{
        user.save(); // explicit save here
        show(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so this approach is more explicit and requires a little more boilerplate - first three lines to be exact - to match the automatic loading done by Play JPA plugin if the entity id is provided in the format that is understood by the plugin. I was hoping there was a slightly more elegant solution that seems like it should be possible but this is definitely valid and not a huge burden. thx

Answer (score 1):

[Hi tazmaniax], simply try to include both id and model but only include the id in your route.

```
POST /users/{id}   Application.saveUser()

Application.saveUser(Long id, User user)

<form action="@{Application.saveUser(user.id)}" method="post".....
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, looks really interesting will try shortly